# Sometimes my videos play, sometimes the sound and image don't match and sometimes error

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to run a pygame script that randomly plays 6 videos (with image and sound) three times.
I have had quite some issues with playing the videos but I finally got everything to work last night but then I opened Spyder up again this morning and now the image of the videos aren't in synch with the sound and often I get a fatal error message from pygame_parachute. At some point, the first video I played worked but consistently the second one was very laggy, that problem seems to be fixed now but I don't know how :p . This keeps happening and I really don't understand why sometimes it works and then sometimes it doesn't.
I am using pyvideoplayer https://github.com/ree1261/pyvidplayer to play the videos.
This is the section of code that I use to play the videos, if you need the rest of the code it's here: https://github.com/RebeccaJaneScarratt/Play-Video-Code/tree/main

```
def name():
    global trial_number
    global loop
    global current_order
    global current_preset
    trial_number = trial_number + 1
    if trial_number == 6: # when we get to the 6th trial, go onto loop 2 and play all the same videos again
        loop = loop + 1
        trial_number = 0
    if loop == 4: # when we get to the forth loop, close everything
        pygame.quit()
    print('trial number:' , trial_number)
    print('loop number:', loop)
# I want to have different random orders of the melodies, order1, order2 and order3 are defined elsewhere btu for example order1 could be ['1','3','5','6','2','4']
    if loop == 1:
        current_order = order1
    if loop == 2:
        current_order = order2
    if loop == 3:
        current_order = order3
    print ('current order' + str(current_order))
    im = pygame.image.load(current_order[trial_number] +'_name.jpg')
    image_width = im.get_width()
    image_height = im.get_height()
    im_rect = im.get_rect(center = [screen_width//2, screen_height//2])
    display_image = True
    while True:
        screen.fill(grey)
        if display_image == True:
            screen.blit(im, im_rect)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
        pygame.display.flip()
        print('we are waiting')
        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        print('we have waited')
        display_image = False
        if display_image == False:
            video(Video(str(current_order[trial_number]) +'_metronome.mp4'))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

def video(vid):
    global trial_number
    print(trial_number)
    video_duration = vid.duration
    while True:
        vid.set_size((screen_width, screen_height))
        vid.draw(screen, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        video_data = vid.get_playback_data()
        print(video_data['time'])
        print(type(video_data['time']))
        print(video_duration)
        if video_data['time'] > video_duration - 0.25:
            vid.close()
            arousal()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                vid.close()
                arousal() # this is the next function that needs to happen after the video is played. Unimportant for my questions
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_i:
                    print(vid.get_playback_data())
                    print(vid.duration)
        clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code on GitHub, not in the code in this post, I removed `pygame.font.init()` and
`pygame.mixer.quit()` and now it seems to be working for now.